# Multiple fields in an alertDialog in android not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i want to add multiple fields in an alert dialog in android like name, phone no and address but it is showing only one field of address . I want to have multiple fields . I want user to add name, phone no and address in the dialog box but this code is not working.

```
 private void showAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("One more step");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your address: ");




        final EditText edtname = new EditText(Cart.this);
        final EditText edtphone= new EditText(Cart.this);
        final EditText edtAddress =new EditText(Cart.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

        );
        edtphone.setLayoutParams(lp);
        edtname.setLayoutParams(lp);
        edtAddress.setLayoutParams(lp);

        alertDialog.setView(edtname);
        alertDialog.setView(edtphone);
        alertDialog.setView(edtAddress);// add edit text to alert dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);


       alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

               Request request = new Request(
                      edtname.getText().toString(),
                       edtphone.getText().toString(),
                       edtAddress.getText().toString(),
                       txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                       cart  );
               //submit to firebase
               requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                       .setValue(request);
               //delete cart
               new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
               Toast.makeText(Cart.this,"Thank you , order placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               finish();
           }
       });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void showAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("One more step");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your address: ");




        final EditText edtname = new EditText(Cart.this);
        final EditText edtphone= new EditText(Cart.this);
        final EditText edtAddress =new EditText(Cart.this);

        LinearLayout lp =new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
        lp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lp.addView(edtname);
        lp.addView(edtphone);
        lp.addView(edtAddress);

        edtphone.setHint("Phone");
        edtname.setHint(" Name");
        edtAddress.setHint("Address");

        alertDialog.setView(lp);

        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);


       alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

               Request request = new Request(
                      edtname.getText().toString(),
                       edtphone.getText().toString(),
                       edtAddress.getText().toString(),
                       txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                       cart  );
               //submit to firebase
               requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                       .setValue(request);
               //delete cart
               new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
               Toast.makeText(Cart.this,"Thank you , order has been placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               finish();
           }
       });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `.setView` you override existing view you've set before. I would suggest put them in `LinearLayout` and use it for calling `.setView`:

```
LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(context);
container.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
container.addView(edtname);
container.addView(edtphone);
container.addView(edtAddress);
alertDialog.setView(container);
```

Comment: It works thanks.. Sir can you tell me one more thing how to set hint ?

Answer (score 0):

You must first use addView() to add the EditTexts to a layout and finally call alertDialog.setView(layout)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("One more step");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your address: ");

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    lp.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    final EditText edtname = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    final EditText edtphone= new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    final EditText edtAddress =new EditText(MainActivity.this);

    edtphone.setLayoutParams(lp);
    edtname.setLayoutParams(lp);
    edtAddress.setLayoutParams(lp);

    edtphone.setHint("Enter Phone");
    edtname.setHint("Enter Name");
    edtAddress.setHint("Enter Address");

    linearLayout.addView(edtname);
    linearLayout.addView(edtphone);
    linearLayout.addView(edtAddress);

    alertDialog.setView(linearLayout);// add edit text to alert dialog


    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            Request request = new Request(
                    edtname.getText().toString(),
                    edtphone.getText().toString(),
                    edtAddress.getText().toString(),
                    txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                    cart  );
            //submit to firebase
            requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setValue(request);
            //delete cart
            new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
            Toast.makeText(Cart.this,"Thank you , order placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();
```

As @nikis said..you are overriding your existing view in your dialog. Just think of it as you are creating the layout inside the xml file. You first set a parent and after that you add child views into it.

Similarly, Here you'll have to take a parent first which is `LinearLayout` in this case, and then you'll have to define its Height, Width, and Orientation, and after that you'll add the child views which are `EditText` in your case with height as `WRAP_CONTENT`. And finally you can set your parent view which is `LinearLayout` to the `AlertDialog`.